# Spring Data Rest - POST with relations does not persist dependent entity

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to persist 2 dependent entities with SDR 3.1.6 and `RestTemplate` which are defined like this

```java
    @Entity
    public class Child {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;

        [getters/setters omitted]
    }

    @Entity
    public class Parent {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Child child;

        [getters/setters omitted]
    }
```

Since `Parent` owns the `Child` my order of persisting is the following

```java
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    Child child = restTemplate.postForObject("server-url/children", new Child(), Child.class);

    Parent parent = new Parent();
    parent.setChild(child);
    Parent created = restTemplate.postForObject("server-url/parents", parent, Parent.class);
```

The result is not what I would expect, because`createdParent.getChild()` results in `null` and querying `server-url/parents` shows a `parent` with link to `child`, which leads to a 404 when followed.

```jscript
    _embedded: {
      parents: [
        {
          _links: {
            self: {
              href: "server-url/parents/2"
            },
            parent: {
              href: "server-url/parents/2"
            },
            child: {
              href: "server-url/parents/2/child"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

However there is a `Child` object persisted, which can be queried by `server-url/children`

```jscript
    _embedded: {
      children: [
        {
          _links: {
            self: {
              href: "server-url/exported-children/1"
            },
            child: {
              href: "server-url/exported-children/1"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I think I followed the Spring Data Rest docs, but something here is awful amiss. Can anyone enlighten me please.

Comment: well. try only posting the parent, with parent.setChild(new Child());

Comment: This persists only the parent, no persisted child objects after successfol POST.